# Dual meaning in a sentence: fixation to? effects to?

Tags: meaning, sentence

On page 160 of his 1976 book, The Uses of Enchantment: The Meaning and Importance of Fairy Tales, author Bruno Bettelheim writes:

"**This shows the limiting effects of fixations to primitive levels of development, engaged in out of fear.**"

Does it mean **"effects to primitive levels..."** or **"fixations to primitive levels..."** like "**being fixated to primitive levels...**"?

I really had difficulty in getting it the right way. To me, the latter is the correct one, but either way is possible.

Comment: I feel this may need some more context.

Answer (score 1):

[Bettelheim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruno_Bettelheim) was a Freudian psychoanalyst, and his statement must be understood in light of Freud's [theory of sexual development](https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=http://www.sigmundfreud.net/three-essays-on-the-theory-of-sexuality.pdf). Freud conjectured that the sexual instinct, the libido, goes through five stages of sexual attachment. Psychological problems arise when an individual fails to graduate from an earlier, more primitive stage to a later, more age-appropriate stage. Getting psychologically stuck in this way is called a *fixation* (in Freud's mother tongue, German, *Fixierung*).

Bettelheim is analyzing the fairy tale of Hansel and Gretel in psychoanalytic terms. In the story, Hansel leaves a trail of bread crumbs to mark his path into the forest, a trail he intends to follow to make the return trip out. But birds eat the bread crumbs, leaving the children lost. For Bettelheim, food is the symbol of the first stage of sexual development, the oral stage, and Hansel's reliance on such a flawed method of solving a problem is symbolic of an inappropriate oral fixation. Such a reliance has the "limiting effect" of failing to solve the problem of being lost in a forest.